# FFMPEG - Stream discovered after head already parsed

Tags: ubuntu, video, ffmpeg, streaming, transcode

I am trying to live transcode an RTMP stream to another RTMP HLS stream using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://localhost/videochat/testing -c:v libx264 -c:a:0 libfaac -b:a:0 480k -f flv rtmp://localhost:12345/hls/mystream;
```

However I receive the following error and the transcoding never begins:

```
ffmpeg version git-2014-02-06-474db7a Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
built on Feb  6 2014 22:20:14 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfaac --enable-libfdk-aac --               enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3
libavutil      52. 63.100 / 52. 63.100
libavcodec     55. 49.101 / 55. 49.101
libavformat    55. 30.100 / 55. 30.100
libavdevice    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
libavfilter     4.  1.102 /  4.  1.102
libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Metadata:
description           Chat using VideoChat example.
[flv @ 0x1ec89e0] Stream discovered after head already parsed
^C[flv @ 0x1ec89e0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: none):    unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://localhost/videochat/testing':
Metadata:
description     : Chat using VideoChat ex   ?5P
Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Video: none, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
Stream #0:1: Data: none
Codec AVOption b (set bitrate (in bits/s)) specified for output file #0 (rtmp://localhost:12345/hls/mystream) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://localhost:12345/hls/mystream':
```

If anyone has ever dealt/solved this problem before, can you please share as I have been trying to solve this for 2 days but to no avail!